Ibn Ezra on Isaiah 63:10
Isaiah 63:9-10

In all their affliction he was afflicted, and the angel of his
presence saved them: in his love and in his pity he redeemed them; and
he bore them, and carried them all the days of old.  But they
rebelled, and vexed his holy spirit: therefore he was turned to be
their enemy, and he fought against them.

Ibn Ezra on Isaiah 63:10:1
And vexed His holy spirit . This is a figurative expression. Some understand by the holy spirit the angel of the Lord
Who are the commentators that, as the Ibn Ezra quotes, understand that the holy spirit refers to the angel of the Lord?

@ Shmuel. Ibn Ezra says, that some people, understand that the holy spirit in verse 10, refers to the angel of the Lord, in verse 9. they are the same entity. I'm asking if he refers to the words of other commentaries, midrash etc.

So basically what the original source of the statement is?

@ Shmuel. Exactly. thank you.

I made the question more clear according to the above. Please revert it back if it does not suite you. I also retracted the close-vote, because now it is a separate question.

@ Shmuel. The question isn't a duplicate, and we already cleared that point. Why is it closed?! How could the other Question answer my question?

I did not close it and I vote to have it re-opened because after the edits, it is clear that this is another question. The other members on this site now need to vote whether they reopen it or not.
